# Show result depending on the value of another table

Tags: sql

This has been kicking my butt...

So I have table job:

```
id | date       | time
1  | 02-10-2015 | 8:00
2  | 02-11-2015 | 8:00
3  | 02-12-2015 | 8:00
4  | 02-13-2015 | 8:00
```

Then, user:

```
id | name
1  | John
2  | Mary
3  | Darius
```

And finally, a many to many user_job

```
id | user_id | job_id | status
1  |   1     |   1    | canceled
2  |   2     |   1    | active
3  |   3     |   3    | active
4  |   2     |   4    | canceled
```

I'm trying to run a query where it will return the cancelled **only** when there is not another person assigned.

So in the case of the data presented above it would only return job 4 because job 1 has someone active assigned

```
SELECT 
      user_job.user_id,
      job.id as job_id, 
      user_job.status
FROM job inner JOIN user_job ON (job.id = user_job.job_id )
WHERE homekeeper_jobs.state != 'active'
```

Is returning:

```
user_id | job_id | status
  1     |   1    | canceled
  2     |   4    | canceled
```

Since job 1 does have another user assigned with "active" as status I would not like to show that one.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM user_job 
WHERE status = 'canceled' AND job_id NOT IN 
(SELECT job_id FROM user_job WHERE status='active')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Not exists` operator to filter the `active` records. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_job u
       JOIN (SELECT j.id AS job_id
             FROM   job j
             WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM   user_job uj
                                WHERE  j.id = uj.job_id
                                       AND uj.status = 'active')) a
         ON a.job_id = u.job_id
```